# Infinite Loop in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, for-loop, infinite-loop

I think the Javascript code below works like this:

```
i = 0 first time around.
i = 3 second time.
i = 6 third time.
i = 9 end of loop.
```

So the loop should run 3 times, but in Google Chrome it becomes an infinite loop. Is there something I'm missing? (complete beginner)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i + 3) {
    console.log('hey');
}
```

Another detail: I've been using visual studio code live server.

I've experimented with different variations and get the same problem.

One variation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i + 2) {
    console.log('hey');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i + 3` doesn't change `i`. You probably meant `i += 3`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. So I think the longer form would be: i = i +3